# git - exclude commits when rebasing

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

I have recently merged a feature that was not ready to go into master. Without realizing it I rebased the bad master into another branch that was good.

But now I am not sure how to pull those bad commits out of my other story.

HERE is my git log file

```
commit 15bb0d630f9b9cf59axxxxxxx8100d3a7302
Author: Moises Zaragoza <mZaragoza@xxxx.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 1 11:45:31 2015 -0400

    Some updates 


commit 3caf183afe3f5d7dcfxxxxxxxa239d44c8dfd11a
Author: Moises Zaragoza <mZaragoza@xxxx.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 1 11:45:31 2015 -0400

    Some updates 

commit 3c6c81c7a3215fcdxxxxxxxb56a5540745c397
Author: Moises Zaragoza <mZaragoza@xxxx.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 3 16:59:31 2015 -0400

    Bad Commit that should not be here
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your are asking. Can you try to add additional information to gain clarity ?

Comment: Do you want to remove the bad commit from master as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you haven't pushed your code yet, you can do an interactive rebase and delete commits:

```
git rebase --interactive 3c6c81c7a3215fcdxxxxxxxb56a5540745c397^
```

You will end up with an editor with commit history:

```
3c6c81c7a3215fcdxxxxxxxb56a5540745c397 Bad Commit that should not be here
3caf183afe3f5d7dcfxxxxxxxa239d44c8dfd11a Some updates 
15bb0d630f9b9cf59axxxxxxx8100d3a7302 Some updates
```

If you want to delete commit 3c6c81c7a3215fcdxxxxxxxb56a5540745c397, just delete this line in the interactive rebase and save:

```
3caf183afe3f5d7dcfxxxxxxxa239d44c8dfd11a Some updates 
15bb0d630f9b9cf59axxxxxxx8100d3a7302 Some updates
```

see http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History